# Create columns for added /deleted subid within an id

Tags: python, pandas

I want the below solution for this in PANDAS 3.5. I have the partial solution in SQL in an earlier post.

Hi I have a dataframe as below with thousands of ID's. It has a list of ID's which have sub id's within them as shown. The subid's may get changed on daily basis, either a new sub id may be added, or an existing sub id maybe lost.

I need to create 2 new columns, which will flag whenever a sub id is added/lost.

So, in the below format you can see that on the 12th, a new sub id 'D' is added and on the 13th, and existing sub id (c) is lost. i want to create a new column/flag to track these sub ids. Can you please help me with this?

When a subid gets removed, I would like it to have a additional row, with the is_removed column = 1 on the date it is actually removed. The sample input/output dataframes are below. Thanks.

Sample input dataframe:

```
ID Sub Id     Date     
1    a     3/11/2016     
1    b     3/11/2016      
1    c     3/11/2016      
1    a     3/12/2016      
1    b     3/12/2016     
1    c     3/12/2016     
1    d     3/12/2016      
1    a     3/13/2016      
1    b     3/13/2016     
1    d     3/13/2016
```

Sample Output:

```
ID  SUBID   UPDDATE         IS_NEW  IS_REMOVED
1   a   2016-03-11    0   0
1   b   2016-03-11    0   0
1   c   2016-03-11    0   0
1   a   2016-03-12    0   0
1   b   2016-03-12    0   0
1   c   2016-03-12    0   0
1   d   2016-03-12    1   0
1   a   2016-03-13    0   0
1   b   2016-03-13    0   0
1   c   2016-03-13    0   1
1   d   2016-03-13    0   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this and visualize the results as you do it to use `pd.crosstab`:

```
df_out = pd.crosstab([df['ID'],df['Date']],df['Sub Id'])

df_diff = df_out.diff().fillna(0).stack()

pd.concat([df.set_index(['ID','Date','Sub Id']),
           df_diff.eq(1).mul(1).rename('IS_NEW'),
           df_diff.eq(-1).mul(1).rename('IS_REMOVED')],axis=1)\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    ID       Date Sub Id  IS_NEW  IS_REMOVED
0    1 2016-03-11      a       0           0
1    1 2016-03-11      b       0           0
2    1 2016-03-11      c       0           0
3    1 2016-03-11      d       0           0
4    1 2016-03-12      a       0           0
5    1 2016-03-12      b       0           0
6    1 2016-03-12      c       0           0
7    1 2016-03-12      d       1           0
8    1 2016-03-13      a       0           0
9    1 2016-03-13      b       0           0
10   1 2016-03-13      c       0           1
11   1 2016-03-13      d       0           0
```

Visualize results:

```
print(df_out)

Sub Id         a  b  c  d
ID Date                  
1  2016-03-11  1  1  1  0
   2016-03-12  1  1  1  1
   2016-03-13  1  1  0  1

print(df_out.diff().fillna(0))

Sub Id           a    b    c    d
ID Date                          
1  2016-03-11  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
   2016-03-12  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
   2016-03-13  0.0  0.0 -1.0  0.0
```